# Move (this) element of an array to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I have some html elements that i want to move when clicking on them using jQuery.
I've tried this but it didn't work

```
var element = $('.picAll');
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(element);

arr[3].animate({"margin":"90px 0 0 35%", "z-index":"1"});
arr[2].animate({"margin":"35px 0 0 20%", "z-index":"4"});
arr[1].animate({"margin":"55px 0 0 25%", "z-index":"3"});
arr[0].animate({"margin":"75px 0 0 30%", "z-index":"2"});

$('.picAll').click(function() {
element(this).push();
});
```

I'm still beginner so i'm sorry for the bad code...

Answer (score 0):

### Push element to the end of array

```js
var b = $("b").get();
b.push(b.shift());
$("body").append( b ); // `b` or `$(b)`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b>
```

### Set / Store custom animation properties

Store your Object literal you'll later pass to the `.animate()` into a *custom* Element property (i.e: `anim`).
On element click simply recall it's property.
P.S: note that you cannot animate `z-index`... but here you go:

```js
var pic = $('.picAll');

pic[3].anim = {margin:"90px 0 0 35%", zIndex:"1"};
pic[2].anim = {margin:"35px 0 0 20%", zIndex:"4"};
pic[1].anim = {margin:"55px 0 0 25%", zIndex:"3"};
pic[0].anim = {margin:"75px 0 0 30%", zIndex:"2"};

pic.click(function() {
   $(this).animate(this.anim);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="favicon.ico" class="picAll">
<img src="favicon.ico" class="picAll">
<img src="favicon.ico" class="picAll">
<img src="favicon.ico" class="picAll">
```